# "Unsafe permissions on configuration file `/home/david/.gnupg/gpg.conf" What does it mean and how to fix?

Tags: gnupg

```
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on configuration file `/home/david/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: WARNING: unsafe enclosing directory permissions on configuration file `/home/david/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: external program calls are disabled due to unsafe options file permissions
gpg: keyserver communications error: general error
gpg: keyserver receive failed: general error
```

What does it mean and how to fix?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on configuration file `/home/david/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
>   gpg: WARNING: unsafe enclosing directory permissions on configuration file`/home/david/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
>   gpg: external program calls are disabled due to unsafe options file permissions

This means that your `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` has unexpected permissions for the user you are running as, like write access to "others", another user or the executable bit. This file should always **for security reasons** only be readable and writable by the user, and **no one else**:

```
$ ls -l ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf
-rw------- 1 braiam braiam 7890 Jul  8 18:51 .gnupg/gpg.conf
```

Yours probably has different user or permissions. Check them out using `ls -l ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`. To fix this is simple enough:

```
chown $(whoami):$(whoami) ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf ## if this fails read at the bottom
chmod 600 ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf
```

If some of the commands fails, or you keep getting the error message you mentioned after following these instructions, you should delete the `~/.gnupg` directory, because it cannot be trusted anymore.

```
rm -r ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf ## If this fails, use sudo
```

You can then try to run `gpg` command with the same user that is going to run the script, this way your user with create `~/.gnupg` directory with appropriate permissions.

Comment: On Cygwin, only this worked: `chmod 700 .gnupg`

Answer (score 14):

You probably migrated your `.gnupg` folder from another machine, or tampered another way with the file permissions.

GnuPG enforces private ownership of the folder and some files for security reasons.

These two lines fix the permissions. The first one ensures that the `~/.gnupg` folder (and everything in it) is actually yours. To possibly overtake ownership, it requires root privileges, thus the `sudo`. The second line makes sure nobody but you can read its contents (remove read, write and execute permissions for group and other users). Your username gets inserted automatically, so you can copy-past the lines directly to your terminal:

```
sudo chown -R ${USER}:${USER} ~/.gnupg
chmod -R go-rwx ~/.gnupg
```

Comment: And that is the shortest answer.

Answer (score 3):

I just faced the same problem. It turned out I was running the `gpg` command using `sudo`. When I tried again without `sudo`, it worked fine and no error was displayed. So, it might be the case for you too.