# GPG: unsafe ownership on configuration file despite having proper ownership permissions

Tags: permissions, sudo, gnupg, chown

I'm using Ubuntu 14.0.4.  I want to run a gpg command but am getting an "unsafe ownership on configuration file" error, despite following the instructions here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182938/gpg-warning-unsafe-ownership-on-configuration-file-gpg-fingerprint-on-ubun .  What do I need to do to avoid this error?  Below is the command I'm running and my current ownership rights ...

```
myuser@myproject:~$ sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on configuration file `/home/myuser/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: external program calls are disabled due to unsafe options file permissions
gpg: keyserver communications error: general error
gpg: keyserver receive failed: general error
myuser@myproject:~$ ls -al /home/myuser/.gnupg/gpg.conf
-rw------- 1 myuser myuser 9398 Nov 12  2016 /home/myuser/.gnupg/gpg.conf
```

Comment: Also check `.gnupg`. You can use this to reset all the permissions  for this with https://askubuntu.com/a/593595/15811

Comment: I ran the commands "sudo chown -R ${USER}:${USER} ~/.gnupg" and "chmod -R go-rwx ~/.gnupg" but still I get the unsafe ownership errors when I run "sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3"